# Getting "No Such Module " for some packages in Xcode in my Flutter Projects shifting from mac with intel chip to M1 Chip

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies, xcode15

No such module 'HMSSDK' in my first project while using 100ms for video call and in other Projects

getting No such module 'razorpay', No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit' etc.

I Have Already search try with every possible solutions but didn't get any solution which will work

please Help me if anyone knows to fix this issue,IN Android My projects are building very well

but in Xcode 15.2 or below I am getting same issue in M1 chip laptop Already done Rosseta and

ruby(3.3.0)and cocoaPods(1.5.1) with latest version

Please Help me on this!!!

In my previous laptops(Mac) with intel chip i can easily build my app using Xcode but shifting to M1 Chip laptop getting this error during build in ios Build.

this is my flutter doctor output:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on macOS 13.6.3 22G436 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[!] Android Studio (version 2023.1)

```
✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.0)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
! Error: Browsing on the local area network for iPhone . Ensure the device is unlocked and
attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability